# Prove Gaussian Elimination Preserves this Matrix Property

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Prove or disprove that if a matrix has the property

$0 \neq |a_{ii}| \leq \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\j \neq i }}|a_{ij}|$

Then Gaussian elimination without pivoting will preserve this property

I have tried to come up with some counterexamples with no real success so I am currently moving forward with the assumption that this is true. I have messed around with trying to show even the first row subtraction will preserve the property, but it got messy and confusing.

I assume that the idea that when calculating the number in the next row (ex $a_{23} =a_{23}-\frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}a_{13} \implies |\frac{a_{13}}{a_{11}}|\leq 1$ And |$a_{23}| \leq |a_{22}|$) but i have not been able to followthrough

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $0\ne |a_{i,i}|\ge \sum_{j=1, j\ne i}^n|a_{i,j}|$ (diagonal dominance)?

Otherwise an counterexample is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0.5 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0.5 & 0 \\
* & * & *
\end{array}
\right)
$$
After Gaussian elimination, the second row becomes $(0, -1.5, 0)$, which does not have your property.